# Get data from MySQL database and pass it to jade an access it using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, pug

I have started `nodejs` to make a simple chat application in it.
For this I want to access all users which are in `mysql database`.

My code is like:

**JS**

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res) {

    //connection.connect();
    var sql="SELECT * from users where username='"+req.body.user+"' and password='"+req.body.pass+"' LIMIT 1";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        //res.send('Your data is: ', rows);
        var str="Hi, <b>"+rows[0].name+"</b> ("+rows[0].email+")";

        sql="SELECT DISTINCT username,name from users ORDER BY name";
        connection.query(sql, function(err, datarows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //res.send('Your data is: ', rows+' <br/> All Users are : ', datarows.length+"<a href='/'>Login</a>");
            str+='<ul style="list-style:none;width:300px">';
            for(var index=0;index<datarows.length;index++)
            {
                str+="<li><a href='javascript:;'>"+datarows[index].name+", "+datarows[index].email+"</a></li>";
            }
            str+='</ul>';console.log(str);  
            console.log(str)//gives ul  
        });

        str+="<a href='/'>Login</a>";
        res.send(str);//this not gives the ul of other users
    });

}
```

The above code has problems that I wrote `console.log(str)//gives ul` this prints the whole string like `Hi, <b>Rohan</b> ("rohan@xyz.com")<ul><li><a>Something</a></li>....</ul>`. But `res.send(str);` sends only `Hi, <b>Rohan</b> ("rohan@xyz.com")<a href='/'>Login</a>`.

1. Why this is happening?
2. Is my `str variable` not `global`?
3. Can I use `res.send()` many times, if yes then how?

Can I use the above code with `jade` then **what code should I write for this**.

I found this answer [How to pass data form mongodb (using Mongous module) into nodejs view (using temp engine jade)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686170/how-to-pass-data-form-mongodb-into-nodejs-view-jade) related to my problem

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  mgs(dbColl).find(function(data){
    res.render('yourview.jade', { data: data });
  });
});
```

Then,How to access data in `yourview.jade`

**I also want to know for which type of applications we should use nodejs ?**

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is happening because Node is asynchronous. Your `res.send(str)` is executed immediately after calling your inner `connection.query()`, therefore the callback which adds more hasn't executed before the send.
2. No, your str variable is not global.
3. I do not believe so. If you want to write to the response before sending it, you can use `res.write()`.

Yes you can use Jade instead of what you're doing now. Take a look at the [Jade docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade). They are full of examples of variables being used in jade. To summarize it for you though, you should be able to access a variable with `#{variable}`.

As for your last question, I'm really not sure what you're asking. You can use node for alot of stuff, from [controlling quadcopters](http://nodecopter.com/) to [web sites and services](https://transloadit.com/).